# EDI Receive Pipeline performance issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a file receive location with edireceive pipeline configed to receive incoming HIPPA 5010 837 files.

The normal incoming file size is 4 to 6 megabytes, contains 3K to 5K records. The 837 schema deployed is the "multiple" version which have the subdocument_break="yes". So the file been processed will generate 3K to 5K messages per file.

The pipeline works fine and can split the file into multiple messages as expected. for 1 single file, BizTalk takes less than 5 mins to process.

The problem is when more than 10 files was put to the incoming folder at same time, Biztalk will start process these files parallel. But it will take hours to process these files and the BizTalk Host consumes more than 10G memory.

Some other info:

- The BizTalk host is a dedicated 64bit receive host
- No file lock by other applications found
- Batching setting in file adapter is Num of Msgs in a batch = 1; Max batch size = 10240000
- Rename file while reading is checked.

My question is: Is this performance normal? how can I improve it?

Comment: I suspect BizTalk would probably work better if the files were processed as a batch. Can you try setting the batch count and size limits to be big enough to include all the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, 5K message is not really the issue, it 5 batchs of 5K message at the same time that's causing the problem.

To serialize the debatching you can use an Ordered Delivery Two Way Send Port with an Loopback Adapter which debatches the EDI on the Receive Side.  In this case, the initial Receive Location would be a PassThrough.

You can find several Loopback Adapters here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12824.biztalk-server-list-of-custom-adapters.aspx#jjj

Comment: Thanks. Johns. I will try it. Just wondering if the message context still there after the msg go through the loop back adapter? For example, do I still have file.receivedfilename in the context?

Comment: Yes, preserving the context is one of the options of my implementation.  Not sure about the others.

Answer (score 1):

BizTalk isn't really made to process multiple large files at once, and the file adapter doesn't have any built in way to limit how many files it will pull at once.

There's a commercial solution available to help handle this (disclosure: I work for Tallan and work on this solution) called the T-Connect EDI Splitter (https://www.tallan.com/products/t-connect/edi-file-splitter/).  The use case is splitting the files on a pipeline into more manageable chunks to be consumed elsewhere.  This is not a trivial task, unfortunately.

If your files are small enough to process without splitting them before they hit the EDI recieve pipeline (you don't need to split them further, you just need to process them one at a time), you'll have to come up with a more complicated messaging flow to deal with that - receive them using PassThrough transmit, send them somewhere that can just consume them, then poll them using a second receive location that offers more precise control of polling.

You could also just write your own adapter that offers polling and interval settings, but that's much more complicated and messy.

Comment: Microsoft do give us the code for a file adapter so it might not be too hard to make it behave better. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578623.aspx

Comment: The complicated part isn't so much writing the adapter - you're right about that, as Microsoft provides a sample.  The complication comes in trying to get that to work the way you want it to.  Having an ordered and reliable way to poll individual files is not straightforward - at least not doing so in a way that will be memory efficient, thread safe, and otherwise stable